# Decrypting encrypted shared prefrences

Tags: python, android, encryption, sharedpreferences

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted shared preferences in android for a game I am reverse engineering. I have identified the key that the app uses to decrypt in android's keystore and need help applying it to my script.

Here is the code i am using to try and decrypt the keyset.

The keyset is AES_SIV according to the source code provided by jadx

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def decrypt_keyset(key, encrypted_data, tag):
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_data)
    # key becomes 32 bytes once decoded which siv requires
    decoded_key = base64.b64decode(key)


    cipher = AES.new(decoded_key, AES.MODE_SIV) 


    decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(decoded_data,tag)

    return decrypted_data


keyset_file_path = "/home/un/dev/decryption_tests/an"


# extracted from software keystore
keyset_key = b"shBeeokeqh1k3Mz/2PbbuFC7NG3UZEN9dGOT9VzwG9k="

with open(keyset_file_path, "rb") as f:
 

    tag = f.read()[-16:]
    encrypted_keyset = f.read()

decrypted_keyset = decrypt_keyset(keyset_key, encrypted_keyset,tag)
```

This results in the error "MAC check failed".

- [Source code](https://pastebin.com/Hesxp7za) snippet
- [Test data](https://pastebin.com/gwwqVpmh)
- [Full save](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/euvDxbQd)

Comment: Please share the encryption code and/or full test data. Did you forget to specify the IV (which could then be the cause of the problem), or was no IV actually specified during encryption (which means deterministic encryption, s. [SIV mode](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#siv-mode))?

Comment: The linked code is incomprehensible and also not executable, so it is not very helpful. Concerning the test data: Since you know your files better, especially regarding format and names, please extract the test data. What is needed is *complete* test data, i.e. plaintext, key, IV (if one is used) and resulting ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco I apologise, I forgot to say that i am reverse engineering the app in question. so i do not have access to the plaintext

Comment: Note that you have a bug when loading the data. After determining the tag, the file pointer is at the end, so the ciphertext cannot be read. Fix this and check if this could be the cause of the problem. A second tip, often the IV is prepended to the ciphertext (iv|ciphertext|tag). You can try on the off chance if this pattern was used.